# Gauss's anticipation of quaternions and their relation to congruences

Tags: biographical-details, abstract-algebra, gauss, quaternions

Recently i read the article "**Hamilton, Rodrigues, Gauss, Quaternions and Rotations: A Historical Reassessment**", which can be found freely on the internet. This article is by far the most comprehensive paper i found on the early history of quaternions: it discusses Euler's glimpses of a quaternions algebra, and Gauss's anticipations of it in his posthomously published 1819 fragment "mutations des raumes" (english: "**rotations of space**").

The article gives a quite complete assessement of this fragment of Gauss: it lists (on p. 11-12) several aspects of Gauss's "algebra of rotations", which correspond almost exactly to the eight subsections of part I of Gauss's fragment. However, it doesn't comment about subsection 5; in it Gauss writes down, as far as i understand it, several congruences involving the elements (i.e, the quaternion coefficients $a,b,c,d$) of a composition of two spatial rotations (two quaternions) modulo the norm of one quaternion.

More specifically, Gauss defines the following:

$$ A = a\alpha - b\beta - c\gamma - d\delta$$
$$B = a\beta + b\alpha - c\delta + d\gamma $$
$$C = a\gamma + b\delta + c\alpha - d\beta$$
$$D = a\delta - b\gamma + c\beta + d\alpha$$ and the norms: $m = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2, \mu = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2$, and then observes that, for example:

$$\frac {{C+Di}}{{A + Bi}} \equiv \frac {{c + di}}{{a + bi}} \pmod m$$

One thing that immediately came to my mind is what is "$i$"? he didn't define it previously, and my second question is: what's the meaning of this congruence? in fact Gauss writes six such congruences (anyone interested can find it in Gauss's werke, volume 8, p.359)

Comment: I just want to acknowledge and encourage the groundwork you are doing with tracing lesser known facts through the original sources. I wish I could be of more help but unfortunately I do not have as much time as I used to.

Comment: Thanks sincerely Conifold! It's very encouraging to know that people here don't only view me as a snooze user.

Answer (score 6):

I asked a mathematician who is an expert to abstract algebra and he showed me that Gauss's congruence was actually correct. To prove Gauss congruence let's introduce the following notation: $$x = a+bi,y = c+ di, u = \alpha + \beta i, v = \gamma + \delta i, X = A + Bi, Y = C + Di$$.

First of all, one has to understand that Gauss's notation is different from modern convention in two aspects:

- When Gauss designates a quaternion by a collection of four coefficients $(a,b,c,d)$, he means $a+ib+jc+kd$ (not $a+bi+cj+dk$).
- Secondly, Gauss defines quaternions multiplication in such way that the product of two fundamental quaternions gives the third one with positive sign **if** the multiplication operation is done **counterclockwise** (not clockwise like in modern convention); that is, $ij=-k$ and $jk = -i$. That he defines quaternions multiplication in this way is evident from the bilinear expressions he give for the four coefficients $(A,B,C,D)$ of the product.

Therefore each of the quaternions $q_1= a + ib + jc +kd $ and  $q_2 = \alpha + i\beta  +j\gamma  + k\delta $ can be written as:
$$q_1 = x + jy$$
$$q_2 = u + jv$$

and:

$$q_3 = q_1q_2 = X+jY = (x + jy)(u+jv) = (xu - \bar y v) + j(yu + \bar x v)$$

The complex conjugate symbols appear because of the non-commutitivity of quaternions algebra; that is, $jy = \bar yj$. Finally, to prove Gauss's congruence, let's make the following step (multiplying both sides of the congruence by $(A+iB)(a+ib)$):

$$(C+Di)(a + bi)-(A+Bi)(c+di) = Yx - Xy = (yu + \bar x v)x - (xu - \bar y v)y = (x\bar x + y\bar y)v + (xy - xy)u =\rVert x + jy \rVert ^2 v$$

Since $\rVert x + yj \rVert ^2 = m$ one gets that that the result equals the product of m and an integral complex number.

**Important note:**

The proof of Gauss's congruence as presented above includes one problematic step - which is the multiplication of both sides of the congruence by $Xx = (A+iB)(a+ib)$ and the conclusion that if the resulting congruences is correct than the original congruence is also correct. It should be more appropriate to prove, indeed, that m divides $\frac{||x+jy||^2v}{(A+iB)(a+ib)} = m\frac{v}{(A+iB)(a+ib)} = m(\epsilon+i\pi)$ where $\epsilon,\pi$ are rational numbers. However, since we are dealing with modular arithmetic, for prime $m$ every rational number has an equivalent integer (for example, $\frac{1}{3} \equiv 5 \pmod 7$), so after multiplication of the integer equivalent of $\epsilon + i\pi$ with $m$ the resulting Gaussian integer is really congruent to $0$ modulo $m$ (Gauss does not say $m$ is a prime number, so I guess these congruences are just intended to illustrate a general principle).

Comment: The mathematician who gave this reconstruction also explained Gauss's motivation: he said something about orders of quaternion algebras and the structure of their quotient rings modulo the norm ideal (so Gauss's result can be interpreted as a research in this direction).